# VBA - Not allow duplicates in Multicolumn listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen some solutions for single column listboxes, but nothing substancial for multicolumn listboxes.

My listbox has 4 columns and the values come from 4 different comboboxes where the user selects whatever values they want and then click on a "Add" button.

[image]

Below is the code I'm using to achieve this:

```
Dim possibleProdInd As String
Dim possibleDim As String
Dim possibleValue As String
Dim possibleScore As Double
Dim countList As Double

possibleProdInd = seg_cbb_IndProd.Value
possibleDim = seg_cbb_selDim.Value
possibleValue = frmSeg.seg_cbb_posVal.Value
possibleScore = seg_tb_posValSco.Value

countList = frmSeg.seg_lb_posValSco.ListCount
    frmSeg.seg_lb_posValSco.AddItem
    frmSeg.seg_lb_posValSco.List(countList, 0) = possibleProdInd
    frmSeg.seg_lb_posValSco.List(countList, 1) = possibleDim
    frmSeg.seg_lb_posValSco.List(countList, 2) = possibleValue
    frmSeg.seg_lb_posValSco.List(countList, 3) = possibleScore
```

Is there any thing I can implement to avoid the adding duplicates?

The duplicates I need to validate for are:

- I can't have the same Prod+Dim+Value with different scores, and
- I can't have duplicates (Prod+Dim+Value+Score)

Comment: What are the duplicates you want to avoid? Duplicates of the entire quad or that eg the same ProdInd+Dim+Value gets given more than Score?

Comment: That's a great question! So, I can't have the same Prod+Dim+Value with different scores and I can't have duplicates (Prod+Dim+Value+Score). Does it make sense? :)

Comment: You could make a collection which contains Prod+Dim+Value combined, add to collection and if this combined Prod+Dim+Value doesnot exists add it to the Listbox as well.

Comment: @EvR how does those collections work? I'm sorry, I'm very new to VBA so I don't know a lot still!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do  not believe that there is any functionality in the Listbox itself which allows you to do that.

You will need to code the validation into the Add event. Depending on the number of entries you expect in the comboboxes and the 'result' list, there are various ways of doing this.

Some ideas:

- Set up an Array (n,4) where n is the number of Listbox items and fill it with the existing values.
- Check that the new set of values does not conflict with the existing set.

If you are expecting the listbox to become full, doing that every time the user clicks Add will start to take time, so consider instead of creating the array each time, maintaining a global (potentially limited to that form) variable Array up to date as item are added will save time.

You can also save some time by not saving the selected string in your array but by having a unique index in a hidden column in the comboboxes so that you save that number in your array instead - number comparisons are faster than string comparisons.

You can also play with using just an (n) array and saving a concatenation of the entry IDs plus the score. If each combobox has no more than 10 entries, this concatenation would be eg 27613, showing that the item with ID 2 from the first combobox, ID 7 from the second combobox, 6 from the third combobox and a score of 13 was assigned. (Or just a 3-number concatenation for your first constraint)

In the case of more than 10 entries in each combo, you'd have to represent the above as eg 102070613 (leading 1 added to allow leading 0 to maintain unambiguous interpretation/splitting of the number)

Comparing this concatenated number with the potential new entry should be more efficient than comparing each of the 4 items individually.

Comment: I'll see how I can implement your idea, thank you for the suggestion!